# Why is my Tableview data blank? I can't reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

iOS experts!

I'm newbie iOS programmer.
I want to create app using UITableViewController with SQLite.

When my app boot up, I can see my tableview data.
but when I swiped the tableview, tableview data is blank.

I can't solve this problem.
Please advise me.

My source code is here on github.
https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/ChitaShikokuMock

Comment: ya I saw your code, in which vie controller u meet this problem

Comment: thanks. i hope your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should retain the necessary object that to be shown. I verified your code and resolved by this.

**"Strong"** matters. Object says **"Atleast somebody keep me in memory"**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CSPlaceDetail : NSObject

// Id
@property (nonatomic) int placeId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *number;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *teraName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *teraAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *comment;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *webAddress;
@property (nonatomic) double dx;
@property (nonatomic) double dy;

@end
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for good solution. I resolved this problem.